# How to get the history of all firewall rules on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

We have dozens of firewall rules in a GCP project, and we'd like to do sanity check to see if they follow certain rules both real time and retrospectively for security purpose.

Is there any GCP products we can leverage to achieve this goal?

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) This is not one of them.

Comment: Google does not offer a service that exactly meets your needs. Google does offer VPC Audit Logs, which keeps track of changes such as `firewalls.patch`. You will need to configure something to process the logs. Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/audit-logging

Comment: Cloud Asset Inventory does solve my problem. Though I have to process the json blob in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Asset Inventory's [export API](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-cloud-storage) can export all resource of a specific types at one point in the history.

To see all firewall rule, use the follow command.

```sh
gcloud asset export \
--content-type resource \
--project=$PROJECT_ID \
--bigquery-table="projects/$PROJECT_ID/datasets/$DATASET/tables/$TABLE"  \
--asset-types="compute.googleapis.com/Firewall" \
--output-bigquery-force
```

This will export all your firewall to a BigQuery table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [gcloud beta asset search-all-resources](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/searching-resources) command. Here is an exemple:

```
gcloud beta asset search-all-resources --asset-types=compute.googleapis.com/Firewall | grep displayName
```

The output would be :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Khalid, that also solves the problem :)